# Enumerating all possible combination of values for binary variables

Tags: python, arrays, binary, iteration, enumeration

Assume I have n variables that each take on two values: 0 or 1. If I wanted to enumerate all possible combinations of values, that would be 2^n possible combinations. I was wondering how to generate this in a clean and simple way?

Imagine n=4. We would want to produce a numpy array or something similar like the following manually generated example.

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Note that the ordering matters. The first column always looks at cases for col1 = 0, then moves on to cases where col1 = 1. Then col2 looks at cases where col2 = 0 given that col1 = 0, then col2 = 1 given that col1 = 0, then col2 = 0 given that col1 = 1, and finally col2 = 1 given that col1 = 1. And so on. Basically I would need this kind of ordering approach to hold regardless on n.

Can this be solved through an iterative approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4)` will give an iterator that produces such a sequence. `np.array(list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4)))` will give you a numpy array.

Comment: Does `itertools` guarantee to always format the output as such?

Comment: @flakes "The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order." - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a purely numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np


def bin_array(n):
    numbers = np.arange(2 ** n).reshape(2 ** n, 1)
    exponents = (2 ** np.arange(n))[::-1]
    return ((exponents & numbers) > 0).astype(int)


print(bin_array(4))
```

---

Walkthrough with `n = 3`

`numbers` will become:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]]
```

`exponents` will become:

```
[4 2 1]
```

`(exponents & numbers)` applies bitwise-and from each row in `numbers` to all of `exponents`:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 2 1]
 [4 0 0]
 [4 0 1]
 [4 2 0]
 [4 2 1]]
```

`((exponents & numbers) > 0).astype(int)` reduces this to zero and ones:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: This is a neat solution as well. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's just iterating over the number from 0 to 2^n and printing then in binary notation, so I guess this would work in a simple iterative way:

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(0, pow(2, n)):
    cur = ""
    for j in range(0, n):
        if i & (1 << j): # If the bit is on add '1' to the string
            cur = cur + '1'
        else:
            cur = cur + '0' # If the bit is off add '0' to the string
    print(cur[::-1]) # Reverse the resulting string
```